# ExtJS grid not render correctly

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, refresh, render

I have a grid that when I load the page sometimes it doesn't render correctly. It's annoying and i'm trying a solution to force it to render correctly.
Everything it's fine with the data on it, but sometimes it doesn't render correctly.
This is just when I load the grid for the first time, because after that it renders correctly.
Here is the grid with the render correct:
[image: Grid Render OK]
and here is the render error that it gives me sometimes when I first load the grid.
[image: Grid Render Error]
I have tried all this fixes but none work:

```
grid.getView().refresh();
---
grid.columns[2].setVisible(false);
grid.columns[2].setVisible(true);
---
grid.getStore().filterBy(function() { return true; });
```

After I click on the left grid, it applies a filter to the right grid and if the render was not ok, it becomes correct. So I believe it's a render problem.
I'm asking this question as a last resort. Does anyone have any suggestions?
I'm using ExtJS 4.

Comment: No errors in the console?

Comment: can you reproduce it with a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: @serg I never cacthed a console error. It's difficult because the error appears only a few times on the first load and I don't usually have the Firebug opened at that time. When I know for sure I will answer that question

Comment: @aviram83 I can't reproduce it with a fiddle because I believe the error its because I set the field that its not rendering on the database to be 'Index' and I believe since then it start occuring this error. It may be something else that I have done too. And in the fiddle I can't make the app load records from a database (at least the way that I know how to)

Comment: if you try a simple load from json file?

Comment: Like I said, its an error that gives me only sometimes. If I reproduce it in a fiddle it may not get the error because it only happens sometimes. @serg There is no error in the console

Comment: I see similar symptoms when a column renderer or a calculated model field are throwing an exception. Can you post your store, model or column configuration if there is any custom code.

Comment: @alexandre1985, I'm seeing the same problem in my app.  I'm using ExtJS 6.2.1.167.  Did you ever find a solution/workaround for the problem in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an afterrender on your component. This will force the container layout to be recalculated.

Something like

```
grid.on("afterrender", function() {
            this.doLayout();
 });
```

Or with a listeners:

```
listeners: {
             afterrender: function(e) {
                this.doLayout();       
             }
```